# How to make fps run at the same pace across different clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, time, socket.io

Both of the server and client have the code

```
 setInterval(function(){ 
    player.x++;
    player.y++;
}, 20);
```

I have a node.js / socket.io server where the player's x and y are being updated every frame and sent to the client. The client is also having a different x and y being updated using the same logic. The client seems to be moving faster than the server though so it's making the game not in sync.. What should I be doing differently?

Comment: You'll have to describe in more detail what problem you're trying to actually solve with your dual incrementing in client and server so we can offer a better way to solve that problem.  Obviously, you cannot count on code running at an identical speed on both client and server so a completely different technique needs to be used.  But, we need to know what the real problem is that you're trying to solve in order to be able to offer a better way.

Answer (score 0):

that's a huge and kinda complex topic, I'm not in the mood to google these topics for you; but a few hints/directions. 
This ain't meant to be a full answer, but it's more explanation, a comment can take.

1st: don't increment values, neither in the back- nor in the frontend.
Define them as an animation: `{ startTime, startValue, endTime, endValue }`. Now you can interpolate the current position at any time, independant of the interval.

2nd: you have to account for the time-offset between front- and backend.

3rd: check in the frontend for manipulations of the timer: this is a common way to cheat. Don't take the correctness of the clock for granted.

4th: you also have to account for the ping, when recieving actions from the frontend for example, you should subtract the ping to know when the action has really been made. And don't forget to check the ping over and over again: it might change over time.
And again, you can only trust your own clock, and you should check for manipulations (eg. artificially slowing down the connection). google `ping-cheater`, ...

finally: You're not the first one to create a real-time game. Search for these topics, they have been solved, and they have been asked by other people in the past. 
Search especially in the flash-community. Flash still is a popular gaming-platform, and AS3-code should be pretty easy to understand and to port to JS.

Comment: The only answer I was really looking for was your first point, I already did a bunch of research on the topic and I have a system I want to implement but I just really dumbed down my code for this question.

I don't know what you mean by define them as an animation though..

Comment: that would have been good to mention, since I've already seen such code in production; usually by unexperienced developer; about the animation, I've made a (very) fast [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyy5bku6/1/) so you get an idea. maybe *animation* is the wrong wording, but *tween* is almost unknown outside the flash-world

Answer (score 0):

It was actually really really easy, anyone with the same problem just read this article. https://www.viget.com/articles/time-based-animation

The simplest way to put it "move based on how much time has passed since you've last moved" So just find a deltaTime variable by subtracting time_now from time_then.

This is what my updatePosition function looks like now

```
self.updatePosition = function(){
            var now_time = (new Date).getTime();
            var delta_time = now_time - self.then_time;
            self.x += delta_time * self.velocityX;
            self.y += delta_time * self.velocityY;
            self.then_time = now_time;
        }
```

Just set the then_time in your initialization or whenever your character can first start moving.